# How can I make secretOrPrivateKey asymmetric key when using RS256 in NodeJS + TypeScript applicatn

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I'm trying to authenticate users by signing the JWT with a private key and RS256 algorithm, but each time I try it, I got back:

> Error: secreteOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from 'config';

const privateKey = config.get<string>('privateKey');
const publicKey = config.get<string>('publicKey');

export function signJwt(object: Object, options?: jwt.SignOptions | undefined) {
  console.log(privateKey);
  return jwt.sign(object, privateKey, {
    ...(options && options),
    algorithm: 'RS256',
  });
}
```